# solving a recurrence without initial conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have been working on this problem for two days... I can only get as the characteristic part of the recurrence,
I just can't figure out a proper guess for the particular solution.

$$T(n+2)-4T(n+1)+4T(n)=2^n+7$$
Where the characteristic part is
$$T(n) = a\cdot2^n + b\cdot2\cdot n\cdot2^n$$

Where a and b are constants

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+2}+4a_{n+1}-4a_n=2^n+7$$

$r-2=0$, $r=2$

$$a_n^{(\bar h)}=c_12^n+c_2n2^n$$

Guess: $\alpha2^n+\beta$

$$(\alpha2^n+\beta)+4(\alpha2^{n-1}+\beta)-4(\alpha2^{n-2}+\beta)$$

$$(\alpha2^n+\beta)+\alpha2^{n+1}+\underline{4\beta}-4\alpha2^{n-2}-\underline{4\beta}=2^n+7$$

$$\begin{align*}
\alpha2^n+\alpha2^{n+1}-4\alpha2^{n-2}&=2^n\\
\beta&=7
\end{align*}$$

$$\underline{\alpha}+2\alpha-\underline{\alpha}=1$$

$$2\alpha=1$$

$$\alpha=\frac12$$

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=c_12^n+c_2n2^n+\frac122^n+7\\
&=c_12^n+c_2n2^n+2^{n-1}+7
\end{align*}$$

I have tried this, can anyone please tell me if I have committed a mistake and give me sugguestions on how to fix it.